# Allocating datastore id using PRNG

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

Google Cloud Datastore documents that if an entity id needs to be pre-allocated, then one should use the `allocateIds` method:
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#keys

That method seems to make a REST or RPC call which has latency. I'd like to avoid that latency by using a PRNG in my Kubernetes Engine application. Here's the scala code:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom

class RandomFactory {

  protected val r = new SecureRandom

  def randomLong: Long = r.nextLong

  def randomLong(min: Long, max: Long): Long =
    // Unfortunately, Java didn't make Random.internalNextLong public,
    // so we have to get to it in an indirect way.
    r.longs(1, min, max).toArray.head

  // id may be any value in the range (1, MAX_SAFE_INTEGER),
  // so that it can be represented in Javascript.
  // TODO: randomId is used in production, and might be susceptible to
  // TODO: blocking if /dev/random does not contain entropy.
  // TODO: Keep an eye on this concern.
  def randomId: Long =
    randomLong(1, RandomFactory.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
}

object RandomFactory extends RandomFactory {

  // MAX_SAFE_INTEGER is es6 Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
  val MAX_SAFE_INTEGER = 9007199254740991L
}
```

I also plan to install `haveged` in the pod to help with entropy.

I understand `allocateIds` ensures that an ID is not already in use. But in my particular use case, there are two mitigating factors to overlooking that concern:

1. Based on entity count, the chance of a conflict is 1 in 100 million.
2. This particular entity type is non-essential, and can afford a "once in a blue moon" conflict.

I am more concerned about even distribution in keyspace, because that is normal use case concern.

Will this approach work, particularly with even distribution in keyspace? Is the `allocatedIds` method essential, or does it just help developers avoid simple mistakes?

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of collisions use more bits -- for all practical purposes 128 [See statistics behind [UUID V4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)] will ***never*** generate a collision.

Another technique is to insert new entities with a shorter random number and handle the error Cloud Datastore returns if they already exist by trying again with a new ID (until you happen upon one that *isn't currently in use*).

As far as the key distribution goes: the keys will be randomly distributed within the key space will keep Cloud Datastore happy.

Comment: Thanks. Can you comment please on my particular solution above?

Answer (score -1):

Given that you don't want the entity identifier to be based on an external value, you should allow Cloud Datastore to [allocate IDs for you](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#assigning_identifiers).  This way you won't have any conflicts.  The IDs allocated by Cloud Datastore will be appropriately scattered through the key space.