# RNG on Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: docker, random, kubernetes, virtual-machine, google-kubernetes-engine

I need to be able to produce random longs using Java `SecureRandom` in an application running on Google Kubernetes Engine. The rate may vary based on day and time, perhaps from as low as 1 per minute to as high as 20 per second.

To assist RNG, we would install either `haveged` or `rng-tools` in the container.

Will GKE be capable of supporting this scenario with high-quality random distribution of longs without blocking? Which of `haveged` or `rng-tools` is more capable for this scenario?

I asked a related question here but didn't get a satisfactory answer:
[Allocating datastore id using PRNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56989788/allocating-datastore-id-using-prng)

Comment: I don't see this being a problem as long as you use a scalable deployment. I honestly can't say which of the two options would be better to use

Comment: Thanks @PatrickW. What do you mean by "scalable deployment"? Are you referring to blocking on /dev/random?

Comment: No scalable as pods that can scale up depending on the workload. So like using a horizontal pod autoscaler with your deployment

Comment: Sure it will auto scale. But what does that have to do with RNG?

Comment: You asked if GKE can support it, the answer to that is yes. unless I am misunderstanding your question